# Есть ли модули для УДОБНОГО и ЛЕГКОГО скрейпинга headers после авторизации?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! Есть сайт, после авторизации передает в response хедеры, меня интересует есть ли удобный модуль для их скрейпинга и перевода в формат типа:

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'пример',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Referer': 'пример',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'пример',
    'Cookie': '__cfduid=d1111; YII_CSRF_TOKEN=111
    'Connection': 'close',
}
```

надоело просто изобретать велосипед) 
PS на гитхабе и pypi смотрел

Comment: Эм, ну, просто `headers = dict(response.headers)` ?

Comment: @andreymal слишком сложно!

Comment: @nick-volynkin вместо сарказма лучше бы изучили вопрос, потому что в response.headers не получишь cookies (точнее не всегда), нужно получать их отдельно запросом response.cookies и пихать в хедеры, что неудобно. так что просьба не флудить

Comment: @dimahimma как насчет `dict(response.headers).update(dict(response.cookies))`?

Answer (score 1):

Есть [Requests](https://github.com/requests/requests), удобная.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-headers - про то, как вытащить headers.